# Crontab not really running as root when it should be?

Tags: bash, cron

I have Ubuntu and am running under the user "alex". I've got the following bash script running as root with crontab however it sends me an email and it looks like it hasn't run correctly as the result is not present:

/dev/sda - Reallocated_Sector_Ct is

However if I run the crontab job manually from webmin, it works without issues. But when it's scheduled to run, that's when it fails. Maybe it's not really running as root?

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
SMARTCHECK=`smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep "Reallocated_Sector_Ct" | awk 'NR==1 {print $10}'`
echo "/dev/sda - Reallocated_Sector_Ct is $SMARTCHECK"
if [ "$SMARTCHECK" != "0" ]; then
    mail -s "Failing: /dev/sda" alex <<< "/dev/sda - Reallocated_Sector_Ct is $SMARTCHECK"
fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: how did you set up it to be launched from root? Is it in root's crontab, sudo without password, smth else?

Comment: First guess would be `smartctl` is not in the path? And try to run the command with `env -i` from the commandline, does it work then?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing how you set up the crontab.

Comment: Thanks Wikken, seems like I had to add the complete path - I'm now running /usr/sbin/smartctl.   

I added this crontab from webmin.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities to run scripts using cron:

1. You use system crontab `/etc/crontab`. In this case they run as root.
2. You use users' crontabs, which are accessible using `crontab -e`. In this case they run with privileges of the user, that has added the command to his crontab.

Comment: And the `root` user has its own user crontab. Remember that user crontabs and system crontabs have different syntax; the latter specify the account (not necessarily `root`) under which to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

more possible issues in cronjob scripting.

- change all commands in script with full path, especially the command `smartctl`
- check your system has /bin/bash, not /usr/bin/bash, or set the cronjob as:

  0 * * * * ~/.profile;/usr/bin/bash YOUR_SCRIPT
- check the mail in alex account, if there are any  error messages can be found.